# Strange errors with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and as a result of playing around with it in sharelatex, I've started a few pages on calculus. I want to render this graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = sin(x)$}
  ] 
    \addplot {sin(x)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\end{document}
```

but it renders a wrong one, a graph I used before (f(x) = x/2).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. As it stands, your question is not answerable. Please add the full, compilable code, not only fragments

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code to provide a complete minimal example which reproduces the problem when we compile it. Are you sure that you don't just have an error so that the compilation of the new document does not succeed? Off-topic: don't use `\\ ` for line breaks outside special environments such as `tabular` and `array`.

Comment: How do I conviniently make line breaks, then?

Comment: to see sinus function you should define domain. for example `\addplot[domain=-180:180] {sin(x)};`

Comment: @WzYDWzt: Your code does not show that you use `f(x) = x/2` ....

Comment: @Zarko: Good idea: The plot looks linear, but not with slope 1/2 (as reported)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What do you expect me to do, post 50+ lines of code?

Comment: @Zarko That worked. Thanks. What exactly is the domain?

Comment: \addplot {sin(deg(x))};

Comment: @WzYDWzt, see my answer below. Domain is math term .... the function is defined on it. For example on values between -180 degree and 180 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing your code to MWE and defining domain for `sin(x)` I obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = \sin(x)$}
  ]
    \addplot[domain=-180:180] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For more smooth curve you can define number of samples or add option `smooth` to `addplot`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

Use `\sin` instead of `sin`

The sin function uses degrees, not radians

The samples option indicates at how many points the function should be evaluated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$f(x) = \sin(x)$}
  ] 
    \addplot[samples=200] {sin(180*x/3.14159)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]